# Minikube start failing with addon/coredns

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubectl, minikube

While executing minikube start --vm-driver=none on Amazon linux EC2, getting below errors:

[image]

Below are the current configurations:
docker version: 20.10.7,
kubectl version: v1.19.0,
minikube version: v1.19.0

What is causing this error and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try minikube latest?

If you can't it, you try to downgrade docker version(v19.03) and change cgroupfs to systemd in '/etc/docker/daemon.json' file.

```
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
}
```

Comment: I've already added --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd in ExecStart field in /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service. When I do docker info, I could see cgroupdriver as systemd.  Additionally I've added cgroupsdriver: systemd in /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml file too.  I've tried combinations of above. Nothing worked. Still the same error. I did execute commands: minikube delete --purge --all,
docker system prune  and resinstalled docker, kubectl, minikube. Still the same error at minikube start

Comment: I'm facing same issue with minikube versions : v1.19.0 and v1.21.0. I have to either of these 2 versions

Comment: Hmm.. Can I know your ec2 type?

Comment: Instance type is m5.4xlarge